# iPhone app to transfer text messages backed up in IMAP account to text messaging app (similar to Android's SMS Backup+)?

Tags: iphone, text, imap

On my Android device I use an app called [SMS Backup+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync&utm_source=apkdot.com).

I think its pretty cool, it connects to my IMAP server and creates a folder to store all the text messages and phone calls as a backup. I can easily use another Android device with this app and pull all my texts and they go right into my text messaging app.

Has anyone used this before in order to pull all the texts to iPhone? There doesn't seem to be an app for that...

Comment: I think the only way you'll be able to get those text messages on your iPhone is via [Move to iOS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apple.movetoios&hl=en_US&gl=US).

Comment: What would “pull all the texts to iPhone” look like in the end? It’s not clear what effect on an iPhone you seek. There are many mail apps that see IMAP content, including the native app.

Comment: Pull as in download. Sms. Backup+ can download them and put them into your txt app. I assume if I could simply download them I could place them in a certain folder an txt app would recognize it. However since apple keep everything close I doubt my idea would work

Answer (score 0):

Apple wrote an app to run on Android and copy your text history (and a lot more) to iPhone. Why not get one android device set, all downloaded the full SMS and migrate it over?

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201196

They have a direct download if you don’t use the Google play store, too.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205042

Comment: ya I tried installing that one. It asked to grant access to my location and I denied it and it wouldn't let me install it.  Why would they need access to my location..
Either way I was looking for more of a process like SMS backup+.  I think its great you can backup your stuff and restore, without needed access to more than the essentials.

Comment: There’s not going to be much leverage for sync in a commercial product. Someone in the jailbreak / 4n6 community might have a way to get into the sql database on iOS. It’s fiddly and changes often last time I checked. The big thing is messages is intended to be far more secure than SMS so easy access defeats the whole “end to end” encrypted / no apps can spy on messages design Apple has erected. @gstlouis your question is +1 and very logical to want, just you’re swimming against the current.